# HTML CSS Not Working Properly in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Just playing with a skeleton of a new email I am designing and it doesn't seem to resize properly in IE9.  The main things I have noticed are that the top table doesn't move (right over left) and the bottle table doesn't resize/respond properly.

This is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hirenshah/k7wg3yry/4/

I'm using an application called Thunderhead to actually create the emails based on data from another application, so this is the HTML file produced from that.  Ignore the horrible border styling for the bottom table please:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /><title>Responsive</title><style type="text/css">/* Mobile Devices */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    .table {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
    }
    .container {
        width:300px;
        !important max-width:300px;
        !important
    }
    img.resize {
        max-width:300px;
        height:auto;
    }
}
/* All Other Devices */
 .container {
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width:600px;
    padding:10px;
}
.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.left {
    text-align: left;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}</style></head><body bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><table class="container"><tr><td><table width="100%" dir="rtl"><tr><td class="table" dir="ltr" width="35%"><p>Hello</p></td><td class="table" dir="ltr" width="65%"><p><b>Reference </b><span class="HeaderInline"><b>ABC123</b></span></p></td></tr></table><table><tr><td><p><customlink><img src="http://effervescence.me/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/UnencumberedSharingCircleBanner600px.jpg" class="resize" /></customlink></p><p class="QuoteLetterHeader">Fee is £123.45</p><p class="LetterLargeText_Fixed">Dear Mr Bob</p><p class="LetterLargeText_Fixed">Thanks for visiting our website to get a quote - you'll find your quote below.</p><p class="LetterLargeText_Fixed">Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah </p></td></tr></table><table width="100%"><tr><td class="table" width="50%"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td width="100%" style="border-bottom-color:black;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;border-left-color:black;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:1pt;border-right-color:black;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:1pt;border-top-color:black;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:1pt;"><p class="CallNumber">aa1 a1 a1 a1 a1 a1 a1 a1 1 a1 a1 a1 a1 a1 a1 a1 </p></td></tr><tr><td width="100%" style="border-bottom-color:black;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;border-left-color:black;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:1pt;border-right-color:black;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:1pt;"><p class="CallNumber">a2 a2 a2 a2 a2 a2 </p></td></tr><tr><td width="100%" style="border-bottom-color:black;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;border-left-color:black;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:1pt;border-right-color:black;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:1pt;"><p class="CallNumber">a3 a3 a3</p></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td class="table" width="50%"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td width="100%" style="border-bottom-color:black;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;border-left-color:black;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:1pt;border-right-color:black;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:1pt;border-top-color:black;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:1pt;"><p class="CallNumber">b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b1 b </p></td></tr><tr><td width="100%" style="border-bottom-color:black;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;border-left-color:black;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:1pt;border-right-color:black;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:1pt;"><p class="CallNumber">b2 b2 b2 b2 </p></td></tr><tr><td width="100%" style="border-bottom-color:black;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;border-left-color:black;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:1pt;border-right-color:black;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:1pt;"><p class="CallNumber">b3 b3 </p></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

All this works in Chrome and Firefox so it must be something in IE :(

Comment: please add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> in head tag

Comment: @anujsoft, doesn't seem to make a difference :(

Comment: can you post sceenshot

Comment: @anujsoft, screenshots are here: http://imgur.com/shcK3iG,JJws7bb

Comment: You can use media-queries.js or respond.js to add media query support in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Made changes to your code.Tested in IE. Please find updated code `HTML & CSS` [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hwqzyxmf/)

Comment: I have jsfiddle open in Chrome and that does not work.  The white container does not switch between 300px and 600px (it just resizes with the window size) and the top table no longer moves to right over left :(

Comment: Yes I have removed 'table' class that is used so that the table above logo does not getting re-sized. If you need any help please let me know